# NPM module install error "code ELIFECYCLE" " errno 4058"

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, node-modules

## Error:

Every time I try to install some module using npm I get this output log in console:

```
1:C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g serialport
2:"CALL "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node.exe" 
3:"C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" is not recognized as an
4:internal or external command,
5:programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
6:npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible --
7:are you offline?
8:npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during
9:revalidation.
10:
11:> @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install
12:C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
13:> prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild
14:
15:npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
16:npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34;
17:npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34;
18:npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34;
19:npm ERR! errno -4058
20:npm ERR! @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || 
21:node-gyp rebuild`
22:npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34; ENOENT
23:npm ERR!
24:npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install script.
25:npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
26:
27:npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
28:npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-25T14_44_28_892Z-debug.log
```

*(Note that the line enumeration in this output was hand made and doesn't correspond with the actual output lines. It's just for pointing out things better)*

> **Hightlights:**
>
> - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> - npm ERR! errno -4058
> - npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install script.

This error pops specifically when I try to run the command `npm install -g <module>` or even just `npm install <module>` for when I want to do it locally.

## Also

The output log that you can see between the lines **2** and **4** is something that I get **every time** I try to run a npm command, independently if it is "npm install " or any other.

**Example:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
"CALL "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
6.13.6
```

As you can see in this and the previous example: **even though I get this error message, the command is executed anyways in after said error.**

## Extra info

- I have installed Node.js in custom location `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs` instead of `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
- I have never faced this issue when I installed Node.js before in this computer.
- NPM cache log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOd4uYVjn_ko3ZWZOM8ceavx8w_yYSWY/view?usp=sharing
- > **OS:**----------- Windows 10
  >   **Node.js:**-----  v13.7.0
  >   **NPM:** --------- v6.13.6

Comment: What happens if you do : `node "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Documents\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" -v` ?

Comment: I get this: `6.13.6`

Comment: No error this time? And if you replace `-v` in the command above with `-g serialport`?

Comment: Nope, no errors, it only happens when I type "npm" specifically. But as I said, the command works anyways.

Replacing `-v` with `install -g serialport` didn't give me said error log, but it still gives me the `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` one.

Comment: WELL I FOCKEN RESET THE COMPUTER AND IT WORKED SO THANKS